# rails generate script for adding new pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate

Creating a new page (within an existing controller) in rails is an easy 3 step process; any way of automating this?  Creating a generate script that does the following maybe:

1. add method to controller:

   def newPage
   end
2. add route(s)

   get 'controller/newPage'
   match 'url' => 'controller#newPage'
3. Create newPage.html.erb in the appropriate directory

I'd much rather automate this with a command like:

```
rails g controller:add newPage
```

I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command

```
rails generate controller controller_name page_name
```

it will create

1. The controller if it's not made already, and the method inside it.
2. The appropriate get statement in routes.rb
3. Generate the view page in the controller's view directory (app/views/controller_name/page_name.html.erb)
4. Appropriate tests/helper/css/javascripts

Comment: Controller has already been created... I would think re-running this script would overwrite whats in it but I'll verify.  Thanks.

Comment: If the controller is made it prompts you with what you want to do I think.

Comment: that command overwrites existing controllers... Looking to simply append the action/method, create the html.erb, and append routes/  Thanks.

Comment: Then I think your only option to do this is to write your own generator. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html